# AWS S3 Java SDK: detect time/clock skew programmatically?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Android app uses the AWS Java SDK for uploading user photos to S3.

Whenever a user's phone's clock is 'skewed', this causes all transfers to fail. This is a well documented aspect of S3:

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1#04

It appears that the upstream S3 service reports this error quite clearly:

> HTTP Status Code: 403 Forbidden
>
> Error Code: RequestTimeToo-Skewed
>
> Description: The difference between the request time and the server's
>   time is too large.

However when using the Java SDK, it seems as if the informative 403 code is lost ... and I have only an opaque "TransferState.Failed" to go by (which incidentally is the same error if internet connectivity is lost, if it times out, etc...).

As far as I can tell from the docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferProgress.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.TransferState.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Upload.html

There is no way to get the additional "RequestTimeToo-Skewed" metadata about a transfer failure.

Am I missing it? Is there any way to get additional error information when an S3 transfer fails using Amazon's Java SDK?

**UPDATE #1:**
A commenter kindly highlighted that I should clarity two points:

- I am actually using the AWS SDK for Android (which seems very similar to the Java SDK, but is nonetheless distinct)
- I am using the TransferManager class to perform my upload. Apparently, this is a high-level class that wraps the lower-level AmazonS3Client ... and this lower-level class should expose the error reporting I need, but I am still investigating the exact tradeoffs involved between TransferManager and AmazonS3Client. As far as I can tell, there is no way to get progress information via the (synchronous) AmazonS3Client.putObjectRequest which would be a blocker for me...

**UPDATE #2:**
My sincere thanks to Jason (of the AWS SDK team) for stopping by and helping me out here. The important information is, indeed, available as properties on an AmazonS3Exception if you use certain methods. The docs had originally confused me and I thought that a manual Thread.sleep() loop was required to poll status (and thus I could not leverage waitForCompletion or waitForException), but if you use ProgressListener on PutObjectRequest you can get full progress callbacks and the error-fidelity of AmazonS3Exception.

Comment: It seems like you are using `TransferManager` instead of the low level `AmazonS3Client`. You should clearly mention this in your question. The low level client throws `AmazonServiceException` that contains `errorCode` and `statusCode`. Also, is there a particular reason why you use the AWS SDK for Java instead of the AWS SDK for Android?

Comment: Hi @YosukeMatsuda - thanks for responding. Yes my mistake, I am actually using the AWS (Java) SDK for Android. Let me take a quick look at AmazonS3Client...

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda Looking at AmazonS3Client, is it possible to get transfer progress using this API? I use that to show my users a progress dialog during the upload, which is critical as many of my users have poor wireless connections and some indication of status/progress/bandwidth really helps... Is there a good document somewhere on the exact tradeoffs between AmazonS3Client and TransferManager?

Comment: You can get the progress feedback through [ProgressListener](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ProgressListener.html). In general, `TransferManager` is easier to use and is good for uploading lots of large files efficiently; it automatically uses multi-part uploads for large files. `AmazonS3Client`, on the other hand, gives you more control, but you need more coding to do. Also, [you can fetch the AWS server time using Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RESTAuthentication.html#FetchingDate).

Comment: We have just released a [new version of the AWS SDK for Android](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3DQMUKRPG0AHS/New-AWS-Mobile-SDKs-Release-1-4-5) with the ability to handle device clock skew. You may want to use this feature when you determine the device clock is too skewed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

these two methods should help you out:

- [Transfer.waitForCompletion()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html#waitForCompletion())

  [Transfer.waitForException()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html#waitForException())

If you detect that your transfer has failed based on a transfer progress event, you can simply call Transfer.waitForException() to be returned the exception that occurred.  That exception will be an AmazonServiceException in this case, with all of the info that you need to see that the real problem was a clock skew issue.

Alternatively, the `Transfer.waitForCompletion()` method will unwrap the original exception from an ExecutionException and directly throw the original exception, just as if it'd all been happening on one thread.  This might be a more convenient approach if you want to use a catch blocks to catch different types of errors cleanly and elegantly.

I disagree that the "catch Exception" block is "brutally broad".  The point of that code is to catch any error that happens, mark the transfer as failed and rethrow the error so that the application code can know about it.  If it were less broad, then **that's** exactly the case where exceptions could sneak through and transfer progress wouldn't be updated correctly and would be out of sync with reality.

Give those two methods and shot and let us know if that helps!

Comment: Hey Jason - thank you for taking the time to respond here, I appreciate it. Indeed, it looks like waitForException is the best choice for my scenario. Originally I had skipped these methods since they are blocking and I could not tell if/how to get incremental progress callbacks (and the documentation at [1] steered me towards a looping Thread.sleep() solution). But using your guidance above and Yosuke's mention of ProgressListener on PutObjectRequest, I think that will deliver both #1 incremental progress and #2 the level of error detail I need.

Comment: [1] - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html

Comment: Just a thought: it might make sense to update the TransferManager class docs linked above to use ProgressListener and waitForException instead of the manual Thread.sleep() approach.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'm really glad to hear that did the trick for you!  Great suggestion about the documentation.  I'll update that today to make those methods a little more obvious, and you should see those changes pop up in the next SDK release or two.  Please let us know if you hit more issues with the SDK code, or have any other feedback.  We LOVE hearing from customers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have debugged Amazon's SDK and I'm sorry to say that this information is being swallowed internally. Perhaps I will try to submit a patch.

Details: an AmazonS3Exception is being thrown internally which does in fact accurately report this exact error scenario, but a brutally broad try catch ( Exception e ) consumes it and washes away the specificity.

Here is the guilty try-catch:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/internal/UploadMonitor.java#L145

Here is a screenshot showing that an AmazonS3Exception is correctly thrown with the right info...

[image: debug screenshot]